# Ada2012 controlled types error: call to abstract procedure must be dispatching

Tags: heap-memory, ada

I'm facing a compilation error where I'm not sure about what is going on.

I provide a minimal reproducibable example; if I implement the Initialize procedure, everything is ok and no errors are thrown. The same occurs if class Derived_t has no Hashed_Maps instantiation component, which it's full view is a controlled type and I don't know if it could be related.

```
with Ada.Finalization;
private with Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps;
private with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;

package root is
  
  type Root_t is limited interface;
  
  type Derived_t is abstract limited new Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled and
    Root_t with private;
  
  overriding
  procedure Initialize (this : in out Derived_t) is abstract; --if null implementation is provided, no error is raised
  
  overriding
  procedure Finalize (this : in out Derived_t);
  
private
  
  type array_t is array (Positive range <>) of Positive;
  type arrayPtr_t is access array_t;
  
  function fHash (key : Positive) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type is
    (Ada.Containers.Hash_Type(key));
  
  package HashedDict_pck is new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps
    (Key_Type => Positive,
     Element_Type => Positive,
     Hash => fHash,
     Equivalent_Keys => "=");
  
  --The compilation error is raised before name Derived_t
  type Derived_t is abstract limited new Ada.Finalization.Limited_Controlled and
    Root_t with
     record
       arrayMember : arrayPtr_t;
       dict : HashedDict_pck.map;
     end record;
  
  procedure pFreeArray is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation
    (array_t, arrayPtr_t);

end root;
```

```
package body root is

  --------------
  -- Finalize --
  --------------

  overriding procedure Finalize (this : in out Derived_t) is
  begin
    this.dict.Clear;
    pFreeArray(this.arrayMember);
  end Finalize;

end root;
```

The compilation error occurs at line 33 column 8, just before entity name Derived_t in the private part: call to abstract procedure must be dispatching.

I know that controlled types are usually implemented privately, to hide the procedures to clients; I decided to make it public to enforce implementers of concrete classes to implement the Initialize procedure.

An implementer would do the following to implement a concrete class:

```
package root.concrete is

  type Concrete_t is new Derived_t with private;

  overriding
  procedure Initialize(this : in out Concrete_t); --Implementation will initialize Derived_t arrayMember

  --other Concrete_t public primitives

private

  type Concrete_t is new Derived_t with 
    record
      --Some stuff
    end record;

end root.concrete;
```

I think that, as I declare the map as a member record, and as the map is a controlled type, it needs to initialise its enclosing record but, as the Initialize is abstract, the compiler don't know what to call. Am I right?

I'll privatize the use of controlled types with a null default implementation of the Initialize to fix it, anyway an implementer shall implement the procedure for a concrete class to construct it correctly.

Comment: You’re probably right about the source of the problem. But, given that `Derived_t` is private, I don’t see how implementers of concrete classes can know how to initialize the `Derived_t` part?

Comment: @SimonWright because the packages of concrete classes are child packages of the Root package, so the types extending Derived_t should have visibility of the private spec of Root package. But now I'm facing another kind of problem related to overriding Initialize procedures :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that, as I declare the map as a member record, and as the map
> is a controlled type, it needs to initialise its enclosing record but,
> as the Initialize is abstract, the compiler don't know what to call.
> Am I right?

Mostly on the right track.
IIUC, what you'll need to do is an [extension aggregate](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-3-2.html) -- like this:

```
overriding
procedure Initialize(this : in out Concrete_t) is
   Function Default return HashedDict_pck.map is separate;
Begin
   This := Concrete_t'( Derived_t'(dict => Default, arrayMember => <>) with others => <> );
End Initialize;
```

Another possibility is to use a function to construct your initial value and use that.

```
Count : Positive:= 1;

Procedure Nested_Initialize(This : out Concrete_t) is
    Function Initialize return Concrete_t is
    Begin
        Return Result : Concrete_t:=
          Concrete_t'( Derived_t'(others => <>) with others => <> ) do
            Result.Value:= Count;
            Count:= Positive'Succ( Count );
        End return;
    End Initialize;
Begin
   This:= Initialize;
End Nested_Initialize;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that assignment will work for limited types right?

Comment: @Albatros23: See [Rationale for Ada 2005: _4.5 Limited types and return statements_](https://www.adaic.com/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-4-5.html), which illustrates use "as the expression for the ancestor part of an extension aggregate."

Comment: @Albatros23 — You're right about not having assignment for limited types. You can, however, use renames on the components: `Map : HashedDict_pck.map renames This.dict;`, and since `Dict` isn't limited, you *can* assign to it.